# content editable true parent content hidden issue

Tags: html, css

As you can see ".template-1" with fixed height and ".card-container" have overflow hidden

the issue is when we type some text in .text field its height increases towards top, and all elements from top gets hidden.

If I removed content editable true or pre-inserted text is there..it works fine.

What I want is- Content/text should hide while typing beyond (bottom) of card-container - instead of hiding upper elements ie. image and .title

Here is code snippet

```
<div class="template-1">
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card-content">
      <div contenteditable="true" class="title editable-field">title title title</div>
      <div class="visual">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/155X55">
      </div>
      <div  class="text editable-field">
        Text text 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.template-1{
  height: 200px;

}
.card-container, .card-container{
  height: 100%
}
.card-container{
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.editable-field{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

and Jsfiddle for same
https://jsfiddle.net/qkmLsy4h/

**EDIT**: .editable-field will have height: auto; always

Comment: What do you mean by beyond card container ? Can you explain a little more. Did not quite understand the question

Comment: Add more and more text  in "text " field ..when it reaches at bottom of the parent..it should hide exceeded text..

but right now its hiding above elments

Comment: If you are hiding the exceeded text how can the user type data inside it ?

Comment: With `height:auto` it is not possible. You will have to give a height and `overflow:hidden`

Comment: @SoorajChandran - The basic concern is all content is adjustable i.e. image, title, text etc, but user can add within parent box only, If he excedes that heigh that content will be hided.. so cant keep fixed height for any of elements